# Developing a Social Network: tips, details and information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, social-networking

I would like to create a small Social Network using Ruby on Rails 3. Since it is a complex system, what is recommended for the Information Architecture?

I thought to create multiple RoR applications with a Hierarchical Architecture, each used to accomplish a specific purpose. Therefore I created one domain and more subdomains.

For example:

Main domain: `http://main.com`

All nedded subdomains: `http://app1.main.com`, `http://app2.main.com`, ...

A problem that occurs using this type of architecture is the *authentication* of users, because, while setting the cookie at the `http://main.com` level (so that all cookies are accesible from all subdomains), they are not "followed" when I try to make an HTTP GET calls between subdomains, unless you explicitly pass parameter values of cookies in the HTTP GET call, maybe using a SSL/TSL connection. Is this a right approach?

However, in this case, I can think of using REST APIs and a protocol such OAuth to protect resources...

**What is the right way to create a Social Network? Can anyone advise me detailed enough?**

P.S.: is it correct what I'm saying?!

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at Social Stream, a core for building social network websites :

https://github.com/ging/social_stream

Answer (score 5):

you could also look at Diaspora it's a fully featured social network and they made the source code available on github! https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora

Comment: is it difficult (or unwise) to gut diaspora and make a linkedin clone based on it?

Comment: I think it's unwise to do that (but you will learn a lot). You should build it from scratch driven by tests (Test Driven). Use off the shelf gems like devise to authenticate your users. Then you could take a look at diaspora how they implement certain social features. Then write tests for those features and try to implement them using your own data model etc. But if you really don't have a clue, take a look at Diaspora and it's internal workings to get a better feel on how to start :)

Answer (score 0):

I created and open sourced Brevidy, a video social network.  It might be helpful in showing you a structure for the app.

Source: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Brevidy

Demo: http://brevidy.heroku.com/rob/channels